# I am facing a problem with gedit. When i want to save a file then some warnings are displayed

Tags: gedit

This is not a problem but it is bothering very much.So how to off this warnings like

```
Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported
Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported
Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are just warning because `Gedit` try to set `metadata` on the `file`, if you want to make them not appear, enter this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor save-metadata false
```

Comment: No such key “save-metadata”  this line appeared when trying to run this command in terminal